# How to limit number of clients in django channels' room

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, websocket, django-views, django-channels

I wish to limit the number of users in a room to 2 because I am making a socket game
were two palyers can play a tic-tack-toe or a connect-4 game so I a trying to find some way of limiting only 2 players in one room.

Down below is my comsumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import json


class GameRoom(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_code']
        self.room_group_name = 'room_%s' % self.room_name
        print(self.room_group_name)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()
```

I have removed some of the less necessary methods from this question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `room` model in your project and save the connected users to it, then you can add a `validation` in your `connect` method, something like this:

```
def connect(self):
    self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_code']
    
    self.room = Room.objects.get(code=self.room_name)
    if self.room.connected_user >= 2:
        return self.close()
    else:
        self.room.connected_user = self.room.connected_user + 1
        self.room.save(update_fields=['connected_user'])

        self.room_group_name = 'room_%s' % self.room_name
        print(self.room_group_name)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()


def disconnect(self):
    ...
    self.room.connected_user = self.room.connected_user - 1 
    self.room.save(update_fields=['connected_user'])
```

- Extra:

  and of course, you can use the `F()` function, and make your performance better in `connect` and `disconnect` (useful when many users trying to connect in the same time)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `RedisChannelLayer`, extend them with next method (decision depends on `RedisChannelLayer.group_add` method):

```
class ExtendedRedisChannelLayer(RedisChannelLayer):

    async def count_group_channels(self, group):
        assert self.valid_group_name(group), "Group name not valid"
        key = self._group_key(group)
        connection = self.connection(self.consistent_hash(group))
        # Discard old channels based on group_expiry
        await connection.zremrangebyscore(
            key, min=0, max=int(time.time()) - self.group_expiry
        )

        return await connection.zcount(key, 0, -1)
```

define in settings:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "your_path.ExtendedRedisChannelLayer",
        ...
    }
}
```

use inside the consumer:

```
channels_count = async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.count_group_channels)(self.room_group_name)
```